# Different spacing between, before and after a list of bullet points using style templates in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to do something in Word that sounds simple but I still can't find a simple solution.

Essentially, to increase readability of a bullet list and clearly distinguish each item, I wish to have some spacing between these items. Something like "Spacing after: 6pt" looks about right in my case.

At the same time, I want the list itself to be visually separated from the rest of the text it is embedded in. Specifically, I'd like to increase spacing before and after to about 18pt.

So, this is how it would look like in Word. 6pt spacing between the list items, 18pt spacing before and after the list as a whole:

[image]

I simply can't figure out how to combine the two using style templates. To create the screenshot, I applied one style to all bullet points (i.e. spacing 6pt after) and manually overrode that style on the first (18pt before) and last item (18pt after). And this clearly defeats the purpose of using styles.

Am I overlooking something here or is this really just not possible with Word?

Comment: Will all your bulleted items be very short, only a word or two (at any rate, just a single line), as your example suggests? If so, you can get the effect that you want by increasing the 'Line spacing' value of the paragraph style that you use for list items, setting larger values for 'Above' and 'Below,' and then selecting the 'Don't add space...' check box. Otherwise, you'll have to define additional styles.

Comment: @cnread No, this is really just an example, the items will be multiline which is why applying line spacing will not help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to give the Bullet Points a different Style in Word (recent version) and use the paragraph spacing in the Style to change as you need. This is the best way as (a) the Style will always be available and (b) can be applied to any line or paragraph that you choose.

So you would have Main Style (I use Normal) and the Bullet Style (give it a name). This works for me.

Then, I can easily put an extra line top and bottom in the main style and adjust the size of the line to best appearance.

Here is a complete screen shot of what I said in words.

Space before and after the bulleted paragraph.

New Style applied just to the bullets.

The result looks like (very similar to) your question

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate how this would solve my problem? In my opinion, what you're describing won't work. Even if I have one "spacing after" setting for normal and then another "spacing after" setting for the bullet style, they won't cumulate, the more specific style will simply overwrite the less specific one.

Comment: Set up a new Style and then in the Style properties (unique to that Style) set up the before and after points to give the spacing you wish. Set up a Style as you would for a document, except the Style limits the formatting to the section of text you apply the Style to.  It is quite easy to set up.

Comment: The way you laid out your example can be accomplished with two Styles, one for bullets, one for all other text.  No overlapping needed.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer here but you are being too vague. I described a very specific issue with regards to spacing before and after a paragraph vis-a-vis spacing before and after a list as a whole. After researching this in more detail, I come to the conclusion it's not possible, as outlined in my answer. If you have a solution I'm not seeing, please describe it more clearly, maybe even provide a sample document.

Comment: You can easily add a line before and after a paragraph using the special style. That works also.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of Word with the Style I added to do the bullets. It looks like your question.

Comment: I see I never answered, sorry for that. At any rate, your proposed solution is not valid, unfortunately. All you did is increase line spacing in the list. This will work as long as the list items never have any line breaks. As soon as you do, you no longer have any visual spacing between the list items themselves which brings me back to square 1. I think my answer is still valid: there is no solution to achieve this formatting without manual (or macro) intervention.

Comment: @vic, It will work. But the line breaks in a list item must be made with SHIFT+ENTER. That way, the new line is not a new paragraph and the paragraph spacings will not be applied. A new bullet is a new paragraph so the spacing will be applied there. If you have multiple paragraphs in one bullet, perhaps you should restructure your document, or use a table to layout it. The bullet list is a simple control that has limitations.

Answer (score 0):

### See Shauna Kelly's page on [How to Control Bullets in Word](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html).

> **1. Begin with the end in mind**

---

> To control bullets, don't use the bullets button on the ribbon. That
> will drive you crazy.
>
> Instead, create a list style to manage the bullets, and then apply the
> built-in paragraph styles List Bullet, List Bullet 2, List Bullet 3
> etc to your text.
>
> It's actually not hard to do this, once you get the hang of it. After
> you've done this a couple of times it will take less time to set up
> your bullets than it will to read this article.
> [image: Screenshot from Shauna Kelly's page]
> [image: Screenshot from Shauna Kelly's page]
> [image: Screenshot from Shauna Kelly's page]
> [image: Screenshot from Shauna Kelly's page]
> [image: Screenshot from Shauna Kelly's page]

[Her page](https://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html) goes on to show how to use these. I strongly recommend reading that page. The key is to use the styles to apply the bullets, not the bullet buttons on the Ribbon. This is very much related to her [page on automatic heading/outline numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). The only real difference is using the styles already labeled for bullets. (You could use any existing paragraph style.)

Then, you modify the style definitions to get the spacing you want.

Comment: I don't see how any of this solves my specific problem. Even if I apply a custom style to the bulleted list, there doesn't seem to be any possibility to set a paragraph style specifically for the first and last item of the bullet list. So, either you set one style for the list as a whole, giving up the possibility to define spacing between items, or you set a style for each item separately, giving up the possibility to define spacing above and below the list as a whole.

Comment: You create the list with styles through the multi-level list dialog. You do NOT apply a style to a bulleted item. That is not going to work. You create a multilevel list attached to existing styles. -- To apply the bullets you want, you apply the style to your text. To change the interparagraph spacing, you modify the style. Please, don't complain until you try it. Follow all of the instructions on that page, don't just read it and say this won't work. http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html

Comment: You use one style for the first item in the list. A second for the middle ones, and a third for the last in the list. You can set the first style to automatically use the second style for the following paragraph. The third style needs to be manually applied, but you can use a keyboard shortcut for that. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330

Comment: It may be possible to only use two styles with the setting to ignore spacing between paragraphs of the same style. See sample: http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#question

Comment: "It may be possible to only use two styles with the setting to ignore spacing between paragraphs of the same style". And you've come full circle to what I initially explained.

Comment: I do appreciate your time to answer and make comments but it's simply not possible to do it the way I intended. Yes, you can create workarounds and use shortcuts for styles to simplify the workaround even further. But it's still going to be a relatively messy workaround compared to what should be possible. As mentioned, if MS Word really allowed to differentiate between _paragraph_ styles for the list and separate paragraph styles for the bullets, there would be no problem. Too bad that's not the case, though.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I've come to understand it's not possible.

Since a paragraph style is applied to each list item separately, one only has two options with regards to paragraph spacing:

1. Either ignore the spacing between paragraphs of the same style, in fact creating a spacing style that is applied to the list as a whole.
2. Or create a style that applies spacing between paragraphs of the same style within the list, i.e. between the list items.

Unfortunately, you cannot combine the two in any way for two reasons. First, Word does not   allow to combine styles of the same type. Just as with classes in OOP, the inheriting style simply takes precedence when it redefines a setting. Secondly, in terms of styles, MS Word does not differentiate between regular paragraphs and lists. A list is really just a collection of paragraphs of the same kind.

Confirmed, among others, in the [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-control-space-after-last-bullet/084ff894-9a93-4225-aa99-8d941cccf5af) by MS MVP Suzanne S. Barnhill.

> [...] to have some space between paragraphs and a larger space after the block of paragraphs. There is currently no built-in way to do that.

Comment: See comments added to my answer. Take a look at my sample document on Question and Answer (multiple guess) questions for an example of how this is done. http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#question It is not impossible, but neither is it automatic. You use styles for the spacing.

Comment: A lot can be done but not exactly how you want it to be. I gave a similar challenge and in the end used a macro to set paragraph formats for individual list items